# ReactJS Collapsable Element with "Progess/Completion bar"

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am struggling to make a relatively simple component in React. The goal is to get something close to the following image: 
[image]

In the image there are two components of the same type (lets call them a Panel) in which content can be collapsed and expanded. Ideally a Panel would have a Header Component, a Progress Bar Component, and Content(i.e radio buttons, text, etc). When collapsed, I would like the "progress bar" to turn green. I've started with the following code snippet to create a progress bar, though it is very rough (some of the code in there will be placed in other components and is there for testing).. I am new to react so any insight or direction would be appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

export default class IconProgressBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="progress-bar">
                    <span className="progress-line"></span>
                <span className="progress-icon"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="step-container">
                <div className="step-header">
                    <span className="col s6"><h3>Header 1</h3></span>
                    <span className="col s6 text-right step-summary">
                            <button className="secondary right edit-button">Edit</button>
                            <span className="current-value right"> . </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="step-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Edit: In any answers I'm not super concerned about styling (that can be worked out later) i.e a Circle with a line under it in a collapsible & stackable element would suffice :)

Comment: Have you looked into the material-ui library? Or are you wanting to make it yourself? https://material-ui.com/demos/progress/

Comment: I looked into that a bit, but would prefer a custom method. I guess the "progress bar" isn't as much of a progress bar but rather a border that changes colors & icon when the panel is collapsed.. I am planning on implementing custom logic for when it changes later as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a majority of your functionality, except the binding and some of the styling. You will just have to finish up the styling and add your icons and callbacks to record user actions.

The idea is simple in this case, you have a list of panels which contain a header and a bunch of options to go with each. First, you can simply render the elements and then within your new ProgressBar component, maintain the state of the bar i.e. click to toggle and changing the styles of the bar on the left. Let me know if you have any further questions.

For the sake of simplicity, I have kept everything in a single component, but you might want to change that in case you want to isolate and reuse sub components.

https://react-2nhcbe.stackblitz.io

Comment: Ha stackblitz is cool I didn't realize it was an online IDE that you can take the demo and edit!

Comment: Got it to work in a similar method to yours using your start thank you! Only difference is styling & I've separated the component such that instead of iterating within the component to create collapsible accordion elements, the component creates a single accordion element such that the iteration can be done one level above the component.

Comment: Glad it helped!